# Are the Sudan Airways A300-600 (ST-ATA & ST-ATB) stored in Khartoum?

Tags: airbus-a300

Does anyone know what happened to the last two A300-600R from Sudan Airways? They should be stored but where or are they already dismantled?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are still stored in Khartoum, however they require extensive repairs if they want to be put back in service

Comment: This answer would've been even better if there was some source to back the claim. Unless, of course, if you have seen them with your own eyes? In that case, consider specifying.